# How to choose resistors for a multiple resistor voltage divider circuit?

Tags: voltage, bjt

I am trying to create a voltage divider circuit to off offsset two BJT input voltage is for a push pull amplifier configuration, and I am having trouble choosing the proper resistor values for my circuit. My source voltage is 12V Vcc and I need to create something like below. I know the basic theory behind voltage divider but I’m having trouble making it. Also, the solution has unlimited solutions so what are the best range of resistors to use? I will be powering an 8 ohm speaker with my amplifier. Thank you kindly.

[image]

Comment: You pick them based on current consumption/heat since there is always current flowing through the divider from power to ground.

Comment: How much bias current does your circuit require?

Comment: You may wish to show your whole circuit.  Do keep in mind that if your "12V" source is a car electrical system, you should plan on it ranging from 12V to 14V or so in "normal" use, and you should withstand excursions to +60V and -40V or so (Google "automotive load dump" -- you'll learn more than I know).  If you're aiming for one diode drop across the transistors' BE junctions, then this circuit will be problematic.

Comment: This kind of biasing is not usually done using resistors. The usual technique is to use diodes or diode-connected BJTs to get the 0.6V drops.

Comment: It is simple to calculate a divider if it is unloaded. As soon as you load the output (take current from them) the simple scheme collapses. To work around this you can pass a lot of current through the divider and take only a fraction out. But that is very inefficient. So we need to know a lot more about your circuit (To quote No5 : need input)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/jR12rF3 This is the whole circuit. I know the circuit usually uses diodes but I’m just learning about pus pull amplifiers right now and we are just analyzing results and crossover distortion.

Comment: Also another thing I realize is the load resistance is extremely low if that has a huge factor in Choosing resistors.

Comment: Low load resistance makes it difficult because that load resistance mixes into your divide resistances and throws the ratios off unless you use significantly lower resistances in the divider than your load. But if your load is already low, then that's a problem because lots of current and heat.

Comment: So if I want a 10 mA base current for example, I need a really large resistor for the 5.4 voltage drop?

Comment: With a resistor divider chain, the voltage will cascade down in increments until you get to the lowest voltage possible that is not zero volts.

Comment: I don't understand why, if your focus is to experiment with cross-over distortion and really try and understand it in this context, that you'd resort to a resistor divider. It seems to me that you'd want to design the very best system for varying the spread voltage used in setting the quiescent operating point and experiment with cross-over. The resistor chain forces you to make more measurements and greatly complicates the later analysis. A VBE multiplier and current source makes it very easy to change the spread voltage with fewer remaining complications.